# Are we able to have a horizontal recyclerview inside a vertical recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The main `recyclerview` which is vertical `recyclerview` shows all the deals in the layout

But what I want to achieve is :

> - after the first 10 deals, I want to display a (horizontal recyclerview) of 5 recommended deal
> - after the next 10 deals, I want to display a (horizontal recyclerview) of 5 recommended deal
> - after the next 10 deals, I want to display a (horizontal recyclerview) of 5 recommended deal and so on…

I have attached the image of how i want the design to look like.

I have no clue on how to implement this. But I have both the `recyclerview` working separately. Just not sure how to combine them. I'm not even sure to code in the `adapters` or the `mainactivity`. I have attached the image of the horizontal `recyclerview` adapter and vertical `recyclerview` adapter. Please help me by showing me how to implement this feature. Thanks

Comment: you have to use 6 recyclerviews for this

Comment: You need 2 viewTypes. The first one for the normal row and the second one for the horizontal scrollable view which should be a `NestedScrollView` with another `RecyclerView` inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyAdapter(val list: List<String?>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

private val TYPE_ITEM = 0
private val TYPE_HORIZONTAL_ITEM = 1

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return if(viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false))
    }else HorizontalViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_layout, parent, false))
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return if(list[position]!=null) TYPE_ITEM else TYPE_HORIZONTAL_ITEM
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    if(holder is ViewHolder){
        holder.bind(list[position]?:"")
        // manage your items
    }else if(holder is HorizontalViewHolder)
        holder.bind()
        // manage your horizontal recyclerView
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bind(item: String){

    }
}

class HorizontalViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    fun bind(){

    }
}
```

You have to create Adapter which works with different viewTypes. As an example I've made list of Strings and every 10th element is null which is indicate that it's horizontal recyclerView. I believe that in your case instead of null it should be model for handling horizontal recyclerView. E.g list of 20 items should have size of 22 because there are two horizontal recyclerViews.

```
for (i in 1 until 25){
        if (i % 10 == 0)
            list.add(null)
        else list.add("Hello")
    }

recyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter(list)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzgjF.png)

I've attached final version of my result and that colored fields are for your RecyclerView.
I suggest you to avoid using inner RecyclerView and use NestedScrollView instead and add items through iteration.